# how to select max timestamp in a specific date?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have `date = 2013-05-08` and a column :

```
|timestamp

|2013-05-08 21:02:11

|2013-05-08 22:22:21

|2013-05-08 23:05:12

|2013-05-09 11:02:10

|2013-05-10 09:12:01
```

The result should be :

```
2013-05-08 23:05:12
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: `select timestamp from the_table order by timestamp desc limit 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
    FROM table 
        WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2015-05-08' 
        GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);
```